# Need to remove overlapping Releases/Tags between two separately owned GitHub repositories

Tags: git, github, tags, release

All of the sudden, we are seeing Releases / Tags showing up in [one of our GitHub Repositories](https://github.com/nvisionative/nvQuickSite/releases) from [another GitHub Repository](https://github.com/hismightiness/dnnextensions/releases) (which consequently is also showing our releases).  This is quite weird and neither repo owner has a clue as to how this may have happened.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating a release in GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) means pushing a tag, and adding a release title.

So you might have pushed tags named similarly between your two repos.

The [OP David Poindexter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151096/david-poindexter) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391057/need-to-remove-overlapping-releases-tags-between-two-separately-owned-github-rep/48395139#comment83842610_48395139):

> It appears [a colleague] accidently pushed 14 commits to the wrong repo/branch (nvisionative/nvQuickSite/master).

You can:

- delete the releases
- [export commits through cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) (or [through format-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172120/6309) for two completely separate repos)
- reset your branch (with `reset --hard` + `push --force`, provided you communicate that reset to other collaborators)

Comment: How are tags related to completely different repos?  They're not even a fork of each other.  The code base, solution, and everything else is all different.  The only thing that is the same is that the contributors happen to be in both repos.

Comment: @WillStrohl Not sure: maybe a script which selected the wrong repo when creating the release?

Comment: I agree with @WillStrohl (owner of the other repo).  These repos are nothing alike.  The only similarity is that we are both contributors.

I have confirmed, when I edit my releases (nvQuickSite), directly on GitHub, I see the proper tag associated with each release.  Will can you check yours to confirm?

Comment: I figured it out.  It appears @WillStrohl accidently pushed 14 commits to the wrong repo/branch (nvisionative/nvQuickSite/master).  Should I just delete his releases by clicking on each release and deleting it?  Or is there a way for him to "move" his commits back to his repo?  I found [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another) that speaks of `git cherry-pick`.  Perhaps that is the "correct" way to go?

Comment: @DavidPoindexter Deleting the release is possible (that won't delete the commits). And you can export those commits with cherry-pick, except you should use a range : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309

Comment: @WillStrohl see details above and this should do the trick.  Thanks!