# Copying commits from one git repo to another when a directory structure is different

Tags: git

The following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another) describes how to copy commits from the one git repo to another. I have the similiar case but the directory structure in repos is different:

Simplified example:

Copy from repo:
src/file.cpp

Copy to repo:
src/logic/file.cpp

How to copy commits in such case ?

Comment: Commits are snapshots.  You can copy them the same way as in the question you linked to; they just end up with the files having the file names they had in the other repository, because if you have the *same commit* in your repository that's in the other repository, that commit, by definition, has the *same files* stored under *same paths*. If you want a *different* commit, note that `git cherry-pick` does that sort of thing—copies an old commit to a new different commit. Whether cherry-pick will rename any files, and if so, which ones, is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you would have to do is to add the one of the repository as a remote with

`git remote add <remote name> <remote URL>`

and then fetch with

`git fetch <remote name>`

and use

`git cherry-pick`

to apply it to a commit