# Transfer commits to new remote

Tags: git, git-remote

I have the following situation:

[image]

You can see that I am working on `<red_project>`. First I was working on it in `<green_team>` but due to a reorganization I now belong to `<blue_team>`.

Three days ago, IT moved the code up until commit `dad25697af4` from the `<green_team>` to the `<blue_team>` repository directory.  But since then a few more commits have been made to the code in the `<green_team>` repository.

How do I transfer these latest commits to the `<blue_team>` repository?

Currently in my shell I see the following:

```
<red_project>$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@git.<purple>.com:<port>/<green_team>/<red_project>.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@git.<purple>.com:<port>/<green_team>/<red_project>.git (push)
```

I guess I probably need to add `ssh://git@git.<purple>.com:<port>/<blue_team>/<red_project>.git` as a new remote, but not sure of the next steps then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy commits from one Git repo to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to the `<blue_team>` repository, add the `<green_team>` repository as a new remote reference:

```
git remote add origin_green ssh://git@git.<purple>.com:<port>/<blue_team>/<red_project>.git
```

I would then fetch just the data i needed from that remote, as per [How do I fetch only one branch of a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

```
git fetch origin_green <branch_name>
```

Then i would cherry-pick the commit, or range of commits ([How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)), into the matching branch on `origin_green`.

If no work has been done (or is being done) on the `<blue_team>` repository, you might also just as well `git reset --hard origin_green/<branch_name>`.

Finally, remove the `origin_green` remote reference:

```
git remote remove origin_green
```