# Cherry-pick with changes in a non-existent file

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have two repos with similar architectures:

```
repo1:
 - file1
 - file2 *(this file is non-existent in repo2)
 - folder
    - file3
    - file4
    - file5
```

and

```
repo2:
 - file1
 - folder
    - file3
    - file4
    - file5
```

Repo1 is remote for repo2:

```
git remote add repo1 http://repo1.git
```

I need to cherry-pick commits from repo1 to repo2

```
git cherry-pick <commit_repo1>
```

Usually everything is ok. But I've faced with problem if I want to cherry-pick changes to non-existent file.

Changes look like:

```
 folder/file4    | 9 ---------
 folder/file5    | 5 -----
 file1           | 5 -----
 file2           | 5 -----
 4 files changed, 24 deletions(-)
```

In the end: Cherry-pick merge changes from non-existent file to file3. Only for deleting changes

Someone knows how avoid to merge change to wrong file if needed file non-existent?

Attempts:

```
git cherry-pick --strategy-option theirs <commit_repo1>
git cherry-pick --strategy-option ours <commit_repo1>
```

Give the same results:

```
Auto-merging folder/file3 !!! this file was not changes (instead changed in file2)
Auto-merging folder/file4
Auto-merging file1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy commits from one Git repo to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another)

Comment: @Liam this ticket is not answer for me. I tried  --strategy-option and other. but still have problem with deleting changes in non-existing files

Comment: @liam This ticket does not describe my problem at all

Comment: Put what you have tried (the actual commands and their outputs) into your question.

Comment: I guess it would make sense to ask: what is the history of `file2` in the _branches_ involved? Was it renamed to file3 in the branch that is in repo2? Because I can't think of a straight answer why git would confuse file3 (which appears to be present in both branches) with file2 which is only present in the branch of repo1.

Comment: What I would expect from git in this case is to get a tree conflict because of the missing file in the branch of repo2.

Comment: @eftshift0 File2 was in repo2 a year ago

Comment: I would like to git hadn't done anything in this case. When new changes are added, the git creates a file.
If changes are deleted, it would be logical not to do anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> Auto-merging folder/file3
> ```

This looks like a case of over-eager rename detection: Git thinks `file3` is a match for the missing file, so it imports the change there.

You can disable rename detection:

```
-X no-renames
```

(i.e., `git cherry-pick -X no-renames hash`, rather than `-X ours` or `-X theirs`) to avoid this problem.  Alternatively, use `git cherry-pick -n` so that Git does not *commit* the result, then fix the edited file by checking out the `HEAD` version:

```
git cherry-pick -n <hash>
```

inspect results, make any desired changes including:

```
git checkout HEAD -- folder/file3
```

and eventually:

```
git commit
```

to make the new commit.

Comment: I didn't know about `--no-renames`. @tokek knows all the good stuff, as usual.

Comment: @eftshift0: `-X` or `--strategy-option` and then `no-renames`: it's one of the options to the merge strategy. If you have an old Git you have to use the old `rename-threshold` control knob and lower it to zero.

Answer (score 4):

*Why you get this result*

When cherry-picking a commit, you have to look at the *changes* introduced by the commit.

From what you describe, it looks like `file2` was present in the parent commit, and somehow git computed that `file2` was renamed to `folder/file3`.

And thus : cherry picking that commit dutifully tries to apply that change.

---

*How to fix this*

You can tell git to completely ignore renames (as @torek answered) :

```
git cherry-pick -X no-renames
```

You will probably have a conflict on `folder/file3` (now git since that you are importing a commit which created `folder/file3`, but it already exists on your target branch), which you can fix.

Or you can manually fix the issue at hand after your cherry-pick :

```
# it looks like you want to revert `file3` to its previous state :
git checkout HEAD^ -- folder/file3
git commit --amend
```