# Merge a branch from one repo into another repos branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, clone, git-merge

I had a huge update on repo A's branch and I want to merge this changes to repo B's branch. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the branches on both repos related?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another - Check this.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, code base is quite similar I updated Repo A's branch with Gatsby 3 and added Multi-lang support. Want to merge those changes to Repo B's branch

Comment: I am not talking about similarity in content but rather **history**. Are the branches there sharing common history (in the sense of _revisions_).... just so that you understand where I am coming from and where you should _try_ to go to: You can place the exact same branches (revisions) in different repos. You can have more than one remote set up on a local repo so that you can push the same stuff into different places.