# How to insert old commits from another repository before my commits?

Tags: git

I downloaded a github repository `repo_A`, made changes to it, initiated a new git repository `repo_B` and made some commits. Now I'm missing the git blame. There are many lines that point to my initial commit. So how do I merge the old commits from `repo_A` into `repo_B` without merging the commits made in `repo_A` after my initial commit?

I wouldn't expect any merge conflicts, but what I've tried so far has given me merge conflicts. And since `repo_A` has a long commit history, it would take me too long to fix all the merge conflicts.

I've found a way to do this the other way around: [How to copy commits from one Git repo to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471740/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-git-repo-to-another)

```
git clone https://github.com/path/to/repo_A repo_A
cd repo_A   
git reset --hard old_commit
git fetch /path/to/repo_B

# examine the whole tree
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate

# copy (cherry-pick) the commits from repo_B into your new repo_A
git cherry-pick sha-first-commit-from-repo_B^ sha-last-commit-from-repo_B
```

But I don't see the commits from repo_B anywhere.

```
# check your local repo is correct
git log

# send your new tree (repo state) to github
git push origin main

# remove the now-unneeded reference to repo_B
git remote remove repo_B
```

Comment: You can cherry pick a whole range of commits in one command.

Comment: Oh you are right `first^..last` but still, I think there are some other commits that I haven't reset because of the branches or something. I still can't merge the commits.